# Test if imported method is called

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, vue-test-utils, pinia

I'm trying to test if a composable's method is called from my store. Here's what I have:

`/stores/ui`:

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { useUtils } from '@/composables/utils';

const { sendEvent } = useUtils();

interface State {
  tab: string,
}
export const useUIStore = defineStore('ui', {
  state: (): State => ({
    tab: 'Home',
  }),
  actions: {
    setTab(tabName: string) {
      this.tab = tabName;
      sendEvent('navigation', `click_${tabName}`);
    },
  }
})
```

`@/composables/utils`:

```js
export function useUtils() {
  const sendEvent = (name: string, value: string) => {
    // do stuff
  };

  return {
    sendEvent
  };
}
```

And here's my test file:

```js
import { setActivePinia, createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { useUIStore } from '@/stores/ui';
import { useUtils } from '@/composables/utils';

describe('', () => {
  let uiStore;

  beforeEach(() => {
    setActivePinia(createPinia());
    uiStore = useUIStore();
  })

  it('Sets the active tab', () => {
    let sendEvent = jest.spyOn(useUtils(), 'sendEvent');
    expect(uiStore.tab).toBe('Home');
    uiStore.setTab('help');
    expect(uiStore.tab).toBe('help');
    expect(sendEvent).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
})
```

I've also tried mocking the import:

```js
jest.mock(
  '@/composables/utils',
  () => {
    function useUtils() {
      return {
        sendEvent: jest.fn(),
      }
    }
      
    return {
      useUtils
    };
  },
  { virtual: true },
);
import { useUtils } from '@/composables/utils';
```

> expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)
>
> ```
> Expected number of calls: 1
> Received number of calls: 0
> ```

What's the correct way of adding a spy to `sendEvent` ?

Comment: You can't do that, `jest.spyOn(useUtils(), 'sendEvent')` because `useUtils().sendEvent !== useUtils().sendEvent`. You need to mock sendEvent to be the same function on every call

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks I see now the actual issue, but I can't figure out the right way of mocking it. I've tried this: `const utils = useUtils(); utils.sendTelemetry = jest.fn();` but without any luck

Comment: You need to make `sendEvent: jest.fn()` constant on every call, define it outside useUtils

Comment: @EstusFlask Sorry I must be missing something, I don't see where/how I could do that. If I define it outside useUtils then it will never get called? Would it be possible to add some example code or pseudo-code? Much appreciated.

Comment: Basically `let sendEvent = jest.fn()` and use it inside mocked `function useUtils`. You need `useUtils().sendEvent === useUtils().sendEvent` condition to be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test file - mock the utils:

```js
const mockSendEvent = jest.fn();
jest.mock("@/composables/utils", () => ({
  useUtils: () => ({
    sendEvent: mockSendEvent,
  }),
}));
```

and then update your test to use the mock:

```js
it('Sets the active tab', () => {
  expect(uiStore.tab).toBe('Home');
  uiStore.setTab('help');
  expect(uiStore.tab).toBe('help');
  expect(mockSendEvent).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```